How to avoid adding primary key for required header in Mulesoft DataGraph
I am trying to add link between two apis using datagraph in mulesoft. But when i click on collaboration its asking for field to map as primary key, even for my required header. Client doesnt have any field in response for X-Authentication and they dont want to send it in response. How do i do this without that field in response?

